Applescript: not finding window in splitview
I've a simple Applescript script as following:
tell application "Terminal"
    -- Get the current tab
    set currentTab to selected tab of first window
    -- Set the current tab's theme to Homebrew
    set currentTab's current settings to settings set "Homebrew"
end tell

which works as expected when Terminal is run as a "normal" window, but fails with the following error when in Split View

terminal-color.scpt: execution error: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)

Just in case, what I'm referring to as Split View:

Any way to get around this error?

I thought Macos' Terminal cannot be split vertically, how did you get it ?

Just drag and drop into an app already in fullscreen (Sublime) in my case, doesn't it work for you? On Sonoma but have done it for years.
